# how can control sunlight(opencv)

Tags: c#, opencv

I want to take an original image on c# opencv and take an image every 100ms in real time and compare it with the original image, but what should I do in this case because the real time image is very different from the original image due to sunlight?

```
public void image_binarization(Bitmap _original, Bitmap _search)

{
            Mat original = null;
            original = BitmapConverter.ToMat((Bitmap)_original);
            Cv2.CvtColor(original, original, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
            //Cv2.Threshold(original, original, Threshold, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv | ThresholdTypes.Otsu);
            Cv2.AdaptiveThreshold(original, original, 255, AdaptiveThresholdTypes.GaussianC, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv, 11, 2);
            pictureBox2.Image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(original);

            Mat search = null;
            search = BitmapConverter.ToMat((Bitmap)_search);
            Cv2.CvtColor(search, search, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
            Cv2.AdaptiveThreshold(search, search, 255, AdaptiveThresholdTypes.GaussianC, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv, 11, 2);
            //Cv2.Threshold(search, search, Threshold, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv | ThresholdTypes.Otsu);
            pictureBox1.Image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(search);




            Mat res = null;
            res = original.MatchTemplate(search, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed);
            Cv2.MinMaxLoc(res, out min, out max);
            textBox1.Text = "유사도는 :" + max;

            original.Dispose();
            search.Dispose();

            if (record_score > max)
                record_score = max;
            textBox3.Text = record_score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of non-toy-problem computer vision. Unfortunately full solutions are far too complex to present on SO. Common still quite simple ways are to hold a set of reference images (for different lighting conditions) or to adapt the reference image over time (see ViBe background model or MoG) or to work in a feature space that is less affected by lighting (for example LBP or ORB descriptors), but in the end it strongly depends on your very specific use-case and setting because uncontrolled images' contents are extremely non-linear.

Comment: "background subtraction". opencv has an entire module for that. AND it's an area of research. if you want to understand this situation, you will have to read a paper or two.